# check if radio button is checked wihout using javascript or jquery

Tags: php, html, button, radio-button

I have a form in which i have two radio buttons, both having name attr equal with "status", i want to check if the user checked at least one radio button and if not throw an error message, and set a flag variable to 1 to make some further checks.

i trying by checking that way

```
   if(!isset($_POST["status"]) || empty($_POST["status"])){echo "<p> you must choose missing/found</p>";$flag =1;}
```

but i have the error msg from the beginning before the user press the submit button. I know is because the radio buttons are not set but how do i do that without using javascript?

Comment: Radios usually require using `isset()` and not (just) `empty()`. You should show us the form for this that contains the radios and the form's method.

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to see if the form has been posted **before** checking whether the radio button was selected or not.

Comment: @rickdenhaan thank you, it worked.. can you give me a brief explanation of how  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] works?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains the HTTP request method used to access the page. At the initial visit, the form is not submitted and the browser has (most likely) issued a `GET` request. Most (certainly not all!) forms are submitted using the `POST` request method, so checking for that before attempting to process the form can usually solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form with a button element with attributes `type="submit"` and `name="something"`, a variable is set for this button also in the request. Eg. `$_POST['something']`.

So if you check if this variable is set, you know the form is submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['something'] && (!isset($_POST["status"]) || empty($_POST["status"]))){
    echo "<p> you must choose missing/found</p>";
    $flag =1;
}
```